# Blender 2.8 eevee - Is there a limit for image nodes quantity in a material?

Tags: node-editor, image, drivers, error, eevee-render-engine

I'm making a customizable character with switchable skin via driver.
It is organized by 9 types of skin and each type with 3 make-up as you can see in the 1st image. A total of 27 images. So the driver property Skin range is 1-9 (bigger group) and MakeUp 1-3 (smaller groups).
The problem is it isn't working. If a mute any 3 images, given me 24 images, it works. If I un-mute one of them going back to 25 images enabled, the shader became the magenta error.

So the question is:

- Is there a limit for number of images in a material?
- Is there a better way for me to do this? like a Toggle node or something like that. I guess a script node would be the way to go, but I have no idea how to do it.

Cheers.

[image: The node setup]
[image: Make-up driver rig]
[image: Skin driver rig]

Comment: Hi, were you able to solve the problem? I am having the same problem with a node tree with many nodes and images. The problem only occurs in Eevee and not in Cycles

Answer (score 1):

I recently posted a similar question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/208648/pink-material-when-using-2-x-pbr-principled-bsdf-materials-into-a-mix-shader-w) and had some adequate responses that suggested this is a limitation of Eevee, on both an image texture level, and a hardware limitation.

I saw another post that pointed to [this tutorial by Creative Shrimp](https://www.creativeshrimp.com/procedural-asphalt-texture-eevee.html) on a procedural asphalt that uses "layered" materials, to get around the issue in Eevee, but have yet to try it myself.