# Pink material when using 2 x PBR (Principled BSDF) materials into a mix shader w/Eevee

Tags: materials, node-editor, shaders, eevee-render-engine

When I combine two PBR materials (with Principled BSDF Shaders) in Eevee through a Mix Shader, the output is pink?

[image]

Alone, each Principled Shader works, even if I pass one material through the mix shader, that works. As soon as two go through, it's pink?

I've tried re-creating in a fresh scene with two Principled Shaders, some basic noise textures for color/roughness/normals, but unable to recreate in that case. Seems to be linked to the use of images possibly?

Any help is most appreciated. Thanks!

Have tried the materials on their own, and they work fine:

> Top Principled BSDF Shader works fine on it's own:

[image: Top Principled BSDF Shader works fine on it's own]

> Bottom Principled BSDF Shader works fine on it's own:

[image: Bottom Principled BSDF Shader works fine on it's own]

> Running a single BSDF Shader through the Mix Shader works as expected

[image: Running a single BSDF Shader through the Mix Shader works as expected]

> The mask I am using (for context):

[image: The mask I am using (for context)]

Comment: Further investigation seems to show that this happens whenever there are more than 7 textures/images in use within the material node editor. Any combination seems to trigger the pink output.

A limitation of my hardware or Eevee? Or a bug?

Comment: Hello, are there a lot of nodes before the BSDFs ? Eevee has a limitation on the number of nodes

Comment: Thanks everyone, I didn't include the rest of the nodes as at the time, I wasn't sure that was the issue. They were simple PBR shaders (albedo, AO, roughness & normal) from textures.com, into a Principled BSDF. I wanted to check there wasn't an obvious mistake I was makin, but appears I'm just hitting hardware & Eevee limits.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett please feel free to post that as an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: Ok. I'll do that

Comment: I also sincd found this other thread for anyone else in the future that may want to dig into this a little more: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/177385/how-to-avoid-pink-in-eevee#

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the limit for EEVEE is 24 textures per material. In cycles, you can get around the limitation by enabling "open shading language", but I think in eevee, you're stuck. In the end, it doesn't matter what the "theoretical" limit is - If you hit a point where adding a new texture to the graph causes it all to turn pink, you just have to find some other way around it, such as using a *texture atlas*.